Does Terraform override unspecified fields with default values?
If using Terraform or OpenTofu to maintain cloud infrastructure (say using the Terraform AWS Provider), how does re-applying the configuration affect resource attributes that are not explicitly specified?
In programming language design and usage style, default values seem to be slightly controversial (conflicting with preference for explicitness), but there are arguments (preference of convention) for designing modules to have sensible defaults and then adopting a coding style of leaving configuration unspecified (implicitly adopting whatever the "sensible" defaults are) in most places.
The first part of my question is how this carries over to HCL, that is, whether leaving a field unspecified is completely equivalent to explicitly specifying the same value as the current default, or whether failing to make a setting explicit will impair Terraform's ability to detect and remediate out-of-band customisations (i.e. click-ops changes)? The second part of my question is how this interacts with updates to the default behaviour of, for example, the Terraform AWS Provider and/or the AWS service APIs?
Cloud service providers will typically provide an API web-service for requisitioning, describing, manipulating and relinquishing resources (CRUD). Periodically cloud providers announce changes to their defaults (for example, AWS recently announced a change to the default security policies applied when creating storage buckets). The corresponding Terraform Provider plugin may or may not eventually be updated as well (for example, the change notes for AWS Terraform Provider include several altered default values, most motivated to align with the upstream cloud service API). At what point if any will reapplying the same configuration cause cloud resources to get modified to comport with the new defaults (or in what circumstances is reapplying assured, or not, to produce the same outcome as tearing down and deploying afresh)?

It does not impair terraform's ability to detect changes. The defaults are "enforced" by the provider. If you set the default value (i.e, the value that is set anyway) explicitly, nothing changes from terraform's standpoint. The changes you mention for S3 bucket are usually breaking changes and that should be noted in the docs. This means that you are most likely to hit the problem when moving between major provider versions, i.e, 3.x.x -> 4.x.x -> 5.x.x.

@MarkoE so does that mean you get undefined behaviour anytime you implicitly use a default after a cloud provider announces a change to that default but before the terraform provider gets updated? (Since you don't know whether the TF provider is passing the original default explicitly to the cloud API or not?)

I don't think it's undefined. You would most definitely get an output in the plan step which would show you what and if anything has changed. From there on you could work on tweaking your configuration.

How does Terraform handle attributes omitted from the explicit configuration?
The Terraform protocol/API provides rich mechanisms for providers to handle such cases.
In the the simplest case, a schema attribute that is optional can have a single default value, although the resulting interpreted value may change if the provider version is upgraded. The schema can also specify an arbitrary function for determining what value the attribute should default to, and this can even vary each time a plan is run. Alternatively, an optional attribute can also be deemed a "computed" attribute. If omitted from the configuration, these computed values normally retain whatever their current state is (rather than resetting to a particular value as for a default). The value is effectively marked as "known after apply", and usually intended for cases where the cloud provider will generate its own default value. But there are also more opportunities for the provider to modify unspecified values in the plan, so it really depends how the provider add-on is implemented.
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/sdkv2/schemas/schema-behaviors
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/framework/resources/plan-modification
How do updates to the involved APIs interact with implicit values?
Regardless of what ends up in the plan, the apply generally involves proprietary API calls to the cloud service provider. These API calls may have parameters that are optional and hence have defaults, that may change independently from the terraform-provider upgrade cycle. Depending on how the TF provider is implemented, the cloud API calls may be completely explicit or may leave implicit any call parameters where the intended value matches the assumed cloud API default (as was expected from the time when then TF provider version was released). Implicitness can potentially give rise to bugs where the actual outcome differs from the explicit configuration, particularly if not keeping the library up to date. If the TF provider is explicit in its cloud API calls then any changed defaults advertised by the cloud provider are unlikely to have opportunity to get exhibited, being overridden by terraform.
